# Use separately the links of $links

Tags: 7, theming, hooks, navigation

How to separate the links of the variable $links (in nodes and comments) to be able to place them in various places?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "various places"? Are you wanting the the links to show in different page regions? Are you wanting them to show up in different places in the node template?

Comment: I would like to place the links in various places in template. The links of the node in various places in node.tpl.php, and the same thing for comments. With a peculiarity for the node, I need to place the link "add a comment" in comment-wrapper.tpl.php

Answer (score 0):

You can add variables in `hook_node_preprocess` in the `template.php` file in your theme.  Something like:

```
function MY_THEME_node_preprocess(&$vars) {
  // EXAMPLE: add variable according to view mode.
  switch ($vars['elements']['#view_mode']) {

    case 'teaser':
    $link_text = t('Add new comment...');
    // Build render array for link.
    $link = array(
      '#theme' => 'link',
      '#text' => $link_text,
      '#path' => "comment/reply/" . $vars['nid'],
      '#options' => array(
        'html' => FALSE,
        // Make sure it jumps to the right anchor point
        'fragment' => 'comment-form',
        'attributes' => array(
          'class' => array('add-comment'),
        ),
      ),
    );
    $vars['add_comment'] = $link;
    break;
  }
}
```

And then in your `node.tpl.php` you can check for `$add_comment` and print it out using `render()`:

```
    <?php if (!empty($add_comment)): ?>
        <?php print render($add_comment); ?>
    <?php endif ?>
```

You can probably split out the comment link from `$vars` if that is neater.